# Erro no carregamento de página CREATE

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6

Tenho dois métodos relacionados. `Patrimonio` e `Categoria`:

```
[Table("Patrimonios")]
public class Patrimonio
{
    [Key]
    public Guid PatrimonioId { get; set; }
    public Guid CategoriaId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(500)]
    [Index(IsUnique =true)]
    public String Nome { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
    public decimal ValorTotalDaNota { get; set; }

    public virtual Categoria Categorias { get; set; }
}

[Table("Categorias")]
public class Categoria
{
    [Key]
    public Guid CategoriaId { get; set; }
    //public Guid PatrimonioId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(500)]
    [Index(IsUnique = true)]
    public String Nome { get; set; }

    public  ICollection<Patrimonio> Patrimonios { get; set; }
}
```

Que se relacionam. Porém ao gerar a `View` **Create**

```html
@model ControlePatrimonial.Models.Patrimonio @{ ViewBag.Title = "Create"; }

<h2>Create</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm()) { @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="form-horizontal">
  <h4>Produto</h4>
  <hr />@Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
  <div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CategoriaId, "CategoriaId", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
      @Html.DropDownList("CategoriaId", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" }) @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CategoriaId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Nome, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
      @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Nome, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } }) @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Nome, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Preco, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
      @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Preco, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } }) @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Preco, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
      <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
}

<div>
  @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

Me retorna o seguinte erro quando tento acessar ela:

> Erro de Servidor no Aplicativo '/'.
>   Não existe item ViewData do tipo 'IEnumerable' que possui a chave 'CategoriaId'.
>   Descrição: Ocorreu uma exceção sem tratamento durante a execução da atual solicitação da Web. Examine o rastreamento de pilha para obter mais informações sobre o erro e onde foi originado no código.
>   Detalhes da Exceção: System.InvalidOperationException: Não existe item ViewData do tipo 'IEnumerable' que possui a chave 'CategoriaId'.

```
Linha 20:             @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CategoriaId, "CategoriaId", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
Linha 21:             <div class="col-md-10">
Linha 22:                 @Html.DropDownList("CategoriaId", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
Linha 23:                 @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CategoriaId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
Linha 24:             </div>
```

O que é este erro, e como faço para resolve-lo ?

Comment: Parece que ta faltando uma parte da sua view. Coloca o codigo inteiro.

Answer (score 1):

Para se gerar um *DropDownList* é necerrário ter uma coleção de alguma coisa para ser listada. Não se pode passar nulo nesse caso:

`@Html.DropDownList("CategoriaId", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })`

Aqui vc diz:

> Crie um DropDownList, com ID no HTML de "CategoriaId", usando essa lista **nula**

No lugar desse `null`, passe uma enumeração de categorias, que não terá mais esse problema.

Comment: posso passar uma ViewBag com um `List<t>` no caso  ?

Comment: @RenanCarlos Exatamente. :)